# Angular 2 using property in extended class for ngIf not working

Tags: angular

I have created a angular 2 component for a modal and this component extends a base modal class that includes a boolean property indicating if the modal is opened or not. I need to then use this property in an *ngIf in the template to show/hide the modal.

The issue is that I'm getting the following error when I call my open method:

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'
```

My modal component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cmg-modal-create',
  template: require('./modal.create.html')
})
export class ModalCreateComponent extends Modal {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

My component template:

```
<div class='modal-overlay' *ngIf='isModalOpen'></div>
<section id='modal-create' class='modal' *ngIf='isModalOpen'>
  // modal body
</section>
```

The Modal Class:

```
export class Modal {
  protected isModalOpen: boolean = false;

  protected open(): void {
    this.isModalOpen = true;
  }

  protected close(): void {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Finally inside a top level component I call the modals open method

Top level Component:

```
@Component({
  directives: [ ModalCreateComponent ],
  selector: 'cmg-project-card',
  template: require('./project-card.html')
})
export class ProjectCardComponent {
  @ViewChild('createModal') createModal: any;

  private openModal(): void {
    this.createModal.open();
  }
}
```

Top level component template:

```
<cmg-modal-create #createModal></cmg-modal-create>
```

Comment: Where is `ProjectCardComponent.openModal()` called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message means, assuming you haven't hit a bug in angular itself, that something that is called *simply to retrieve data for rendering to the view* is changing the value. To properly fix it, you need to find whatever it is and change it to remove its side effect.

Answer (score 1):

Import the following:

`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

Then add `ChangeDetectorRef` to your constructor and use `detectChanges()` method when changing boolean value, like this:

`this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: Where would I include that? I tried adding into my component that calls the createModal.open() method directly after the open() call. This cleared the error up from my console but the modal component didn't detect the change. I also tried adding it into my Modal class but that resulted in an error that the app couldn't call .detectChanges of undefined.

Comment: Nope, that just goes back to the original error message.

Comment: Then try adding it to your `open()` and `close()` methods of your `Modal` class. I had a very similar problem and `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` fixed it.

Comment: There is something else calling the .close() method as soon as .open is called reseting the value to false, making it look like this didn't work when it did. The correct placement was just after the open call.

Comment: After further looking it turns out that @Douglas was right and the issue was actually being caused by the close method being called inadvertently. Once I fixed that the error went away and the ChangeDetectorRef was unnecessary.

Comment: Great, glad you fixed it properly. Might as well check my own code then.